# Display more than 10 posts on author.php file

Tags: loop, pagination, author, author-template

it seems that there are only 10 posts being displayed on author.php file. The theme I'm using have just this in author.php file:-

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wt_pagination(); ?>
```

The loop is getting only first 10 posts (of the author). How can I change it to first 30 posts. Without writing a secondary (custom) loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the loop the number of post displayed is choosen fron the option set in *Settings->Reading* in you backend. It affects all the standard loops, not only the author page.

To change only for author page you have to use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook and set the wanted number of posts using `posts_per_pag`e argument:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','change_numberposts_for_author');

function change_numberposts_for_author( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_author() ) {
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 30); // 30 is the number of posts
  }
}
```

See also [is_author() on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author)

Comment: Well, you wrote exactly the same thing at exactly the same time. So, I'll defer to your answer. :)

Comment: Damn you are just quicker :D the same answer twice really isn't necessary..

Comment: **PROBLEM** This has also effected widgets in the sidebar. The widgets are using `secondary loop` to display posts.

Comment: should I post a new question or wait for a fix here? please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this work? `$query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author()` Or am I missing something? And one could additionally add this `if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @G.M. unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ialocin Yes, this is the solution of the problem I faced. Thanks

Comment: Fixed `$query->is_main_query()` in the answer.

Comment: I'd one content area and two widgets in the sidebar at `author.php`. The two widgets are displaying 5 posts using `secondary loop`, __I don't want to change this__ . I wanted to display 30 posts in the content area of the `author.php`, which was initially 10. The initial code you gave solved the problem. The `author.php` started displaying 30 posts. But this had a ripple effect. The widgets in the sidebar using `secondary loops` also started displaying 30 posts. This problem was solved with @ialocin's comment. Am I clear enough? sorry for inconveniences.

Comment: @OmarTariq: Pleasure

Comment: Thanks @ChipBennett type faster bring some problems... :)

Comment: @OmarTariq the problem is not the one pointed by **ialocin**, because there is **no** need to add an extra `if`. The problem was `is_main_query` missing the `$wp_query->` before it. **ChipBennet** found the error and fixed it.

Comment: Isn't the addition of `$query->` just what I suggested, but whatever.. :D